# Confirm user owns a social account without switching to a different logged user (django social auth)

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm using Django social auth to log users in using Facebook, Twitter, etc as described, for example [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html).

Scenario:
A user is logged onto my platform using my native login system. I want them to validate that they own a particular Twitter account without redirecting them to a view where `request.user` is a new `UserSocialAuth` associated with their Twitter account. I want to show the user the Twitter login page but, after they provided their credentials, keep them logged in as they were rather than log them in as a different user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can add more accessible details for your social users indicated here:

https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html#database

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot for the pointer! I think here's exactly what I'm after: https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html